# How to assign initial value to a custom fields in ModelAdmin?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to extends django user auth through onetonefield in model. Here is the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nim = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

With basic admin panel i get to create user instance first and then profile. But i use custom forms on admin panel so i can create it on one form.This is the forms look:

[Profile add form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S6gI.png)

this is forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Profile  


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'nim')
```

and this is admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .forms import ProfileForm
from .models import Profile


class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProfileForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
        user.save()
        obj.user = user
        obj.save()


admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

With this all i can create profile instance just fine. But when i try to change/edit profile it didn't show initial value for username and password fields, only nim field did.

[empty username and password field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHtml.jpg)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProfileForm
    # ...
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(ProfileAdmin, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
        #find the user via user profile forien key
        the_user = User.objects.filter(pk=Profile.user.pk)
        # Initial values
        form.base_fields['username '].initial = the_user.username
        return form
```

also try this and see the diff: (fields lives only after super call)

```
        form.fields['username '].initial = the_user.username
```

Comment: oops:        the_user = User.objects.filter(pk=Profile.user.pk)

Comment: form.fields raise Attribute Error, saying ProfileForm doesn't have attribute fields.
form.base_fields work for me. Thank You